# Drag and drop feature for re-arranging favorite tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

I was adding some favorite tags, I noticed that while adding lengthy tags, the favorite tags section started getting significantly taller, which wouldn't happen if I utilize the empty space in it by arraying the tags in right order.

Hope you get it from the sample screenshot below.

[image: favorite tags]

Hence i went to the *preferences* section in profile to re-arrange them.

[image: preferences]

There I found out that the only way to bring a specific tag to a particular position is to remove all tags (*that you've added over a period of time spent in StackOverflow)* and add them back in the right order you want (*as far as I know*). So I simply started removing tags one by one and realized I'd better write them down somewhere or I might forget to add one or two of them back.

After all that I went back to home page and found that the usual position of my *most favorite tag at the moment* changed due to the re-arrangements I've done to other tags.
Hence I thought I'd set it as the very first tag so that it won't change it's position at all no matter whatever re-arrangements I do in future - Now I have to remove and and add all of them back again.

Can we have a **drag and drop** option, at least in the preference section (*if not possible in favorite tags section in homepage*) in profile so that I can manually re-arrange tags easily?

This might be such a silly thing to ask for, but it's 2014 I don't think it'll be that hard to implement… would be nice to have this option IMHO.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1975/164403) is a similar feature request on the über-meta (proposed five years ago, still not acted upon).

Comment: I only searched meta stack overflow (*i don't use any stack sites other than stack overflow*). Before 5 years it might have been difficult (*idk*), but i think it's time to consider it since it's a common feature in web apps nowadays...

Comment: You might consider using some wildcards there, e.g., `jquery-ui*`.

Comment: I'm using wildcards for *Ignored tags* to ignore stuff i know nothing about. I use *favorites* for easily finding particular stuff...