# Rearrange tags in Favorite Tags section

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Recently I have added [`android`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) tag in my favorite tags list but it is appearing at the end of the section.

[image]

Is there any drag and drop functionality available to rearrange tags in favorite tags section so that I can put it just right after the `c#`

Comment: The order doesn't really matter. Why do you want to rearrange them?

Comment: I have gone through [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261406/drag-and-drop-feature-for-re-arranging-favorite-tags) but as you can see that this question is three years old. That's why i was hoping that there might be some functionality available now. The reason is, every time i need to scroll down to click on this tag to display tagged questions.

Comment: If a feature had been added, someone would have answered that question proposing it. That's how this website works.